# How to enable multiple touches in an iOS app?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Here is the code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  if ([touches count] == 1) {
    // code
  } else {
    // code
  }
}
```

When I simulate the double tap with the Option key in simulator, the code always chooses the first part of my if statement, as if there were only 1 touch received.

Why am I not receiving both touches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`multipleTouchEnabled` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW34) needs to be set to YES before the view can accept multitouch.