# In a cocos2d game, how do I allow for simultaneous input from two joysticks?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

In my cocos2d game, I'm trying to have two joysticks, one for moving the player and one for shooting.  However, I can't figure out how to have touches from both joysticks register at the same time.

Right now, only one of the two joysticks will register a touch event at a time.  How can I get both to take input simultaneously?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable multiple touches in an iOS app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287102/iphone-multitouch-event-cant-get)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using cocos2d, you need to set multitouch enabled on the EAGLView. In your app delegate, add this line after you initialize your EAGLView.

`view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;`